# NuGet statistics - what does each category actually mean

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-server

I am trying to understand what does each line mean at NuGet statistics for a particular package. Understanding these categories is crucial for understanding how is a project/product adopted.

For each of the below categories I copied from NuGet - under what scenario would the count be incremented.

1. NuGet Command Line
2. NuGet VS VSIX
3. Browsers
4. NuGet Desktop MSBuild Task
5. Scripted Downloads
6. NuGet Client V3
7. NuGet .NET Core MSBuild Task
8. NuGet Cross-Platform Command Line

I.E.
NuGet VS VSIX - Likely coming from a download from Microsoft Visual Studio Marketplace.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess nobody knows. Recently (Jan-2020) I noticed that some nuget packages have a lot of downloads by "Browsers" or (unknown) which makes me think that these stats are not real usage stats but downloads by web crawlers or search engines. It makes all these download stats quite useless.

Comment: My delisted alpha version gets hundreds of browser download, it must be crawlers